# How to set the coordinates of the X-axis in the chart?

Tags: android, charts, plot, graphic

Here I can enter the coordinates of Y, data_2_plot.add (edittxt1); ... I have **maxY** and **minY** but I do not know how to do the same for the axis of X? I want to  do  the coordinates for the point (x, y) through the textview ... Sorry for the possibly stupid question.

```
public static void GetMaxKoords() {
int myNum1=0;
int myNum2=0;
int myNum3=0;
int myNum4=0;
int myNum5=0;
int myNum6=0;

myNum1 =  Integer.parseInt(edittxt1);
myNum2 =  Integer.parseInt(edittxt2);
myNum3 =  Integer.parseInt(edittxt3);
myNum4 =  Integer.parseInt(edittxt4);
myNum5 =  Integer.parseInt(edittxt5);
myNum6 =  Integer.parseInt(edittxt6);

List<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();
values.add(new int[] {myNum1,myNum2,myNum3,myNum4,myNum5,myNum6 });

Max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int[] ds : values) {
    for (int d : ds) {
        if (d > Max)
            Max=d;
    }
}    
}    

public static void LoadKoords() {
    try { // Читаем координаты из TXT
        File f6 = new File("sdcard/CameraExample/" +TxtFile.readStringposition+ "koord.txt");
        FileInputStream l6 = new FileInputStream(f6);
        BufferedReader buf6 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(l6));

    edittxt1 = buf6.readLine();
    dittxt2 = buf6.readLine();
    edittxt3 = buf6.readLine();
    edittxt4 = buf6.readLine();
    edittxt5 = buf6.readLine();
    edittxt6 = buf6.readLine();

    buf6.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static Bitmap quicky_XY(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // xode to get bitmap onto screen
    output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);


final int color = 0xFFFFFFFF;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = 0;

// get the little rounded cornered outside
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

LoadKoords();
GetMaxKoords();

String TestString3 =  Integer .toString(Max);

// Set the labels info manually
String[] cur_elt_array = new String[4];
cur_elt_array[0]="";
cur_elt_array[1]="";
cur_elt_array[2]=TestString3;  // max
cur_elt_array[3]="0";    //min

Vector labels = new Vector();
labels.add(cur_elt_array);

draw_the_grid(canvas,labels);
// se the data to be plotted and we should on our way
int  my1 = Integer.parseInt(edittxt1);
int  my2 = Integer.parseInt(edittxt2);
int  my3 = Integer.parseInt(edittxt3);
int  my4 = Integer.parseInt(edittxt4);
int  my5 = Integer.parseInt(edittxt5);
int  my6 = Integer.parseInt(edittxt6);

Vector data_2_plot = new Vector();
if(my1>0) {
    data_2_plot.add(edittxt1) ;
}
if(my2>0) {
    data_2_plot.add(edittxt2) ;
}
if(my3>0) {
    data_2_plot.add(edittxt3) ;
}
if(my4>0) {
    data_2_plot.add(edittxt4) ;
}
if(my5>0) {
    data_2_plot.add(edittxt5) ;
}
if(my6>0) {
    data_2_plot.add(edittxt6) ;
}

data_2_plot.add("16.2") ;
// data_2_plot.add(del1) ;
// data_2_plot.add(Test) ;

plot_array_list(canvas ,  data_2_plot ,  labels , "the title" , 0 );

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
canvas.drawLine(30,30,30 , 30, paint);
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"+"." + "MM" +"." + "yyyy" +"_"+ "HH" + "-"+ "mm" + "-" + "ss");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/CameraExample/"  + "График"+".bmp");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream );
    output.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return output;
}    

public static void  draw_the_grid(Canvas this_g,  Vector these_labels) {
    double rounded_max = 0.0;
    double rounded_min = 0.0;
    double rounded_max_temp;
    Object curElt;
    String[] cur_elt_array;
    int left_margin_d, right_margin_d;

if( draw_only_this_idx == -1)
    curElt = these_labels.elementAt(0);  // default  it to 1st one if non set
else
    curElt = these_labels.elementAt(draw_only_this_idx);  // now just the 1st elt

cur_elt_array = (String[])curElt;

rounded_max = get_ceiling_or_floor (Double.parseDouble(cur_elt_array[2]) , true);
rounded_min = get_ceiling_or_floor (Double.parseDouble(cur_elt_array[3]) , false);

// ok so now we have the max value of the set just get a cool ceiling and we go on
final Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(25);

left_margin_d =  getCurTextLengthInPixels(paint, Double.toString(rounded_max));
//keep the position for later drawing -- leave space for the legend
int p_height = 350;
int p_width = 350;
int[] tmp_draw_sizes = {2 + left_margin_d, 25,p_width - 2 - left_margin_d ,p_height - 25 -5};
drawSizes = tmp_draw_sizes; //keep it for later processing

//with the mzrgins worked out draw the plotting grid
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY );

// Android does by coords
this_g.drawRect(drawSizes[0], drawSizes[1],drawSizes[0]+ drawSizes[2], drawSizes[1]+ drawSizes[3] , paint);
paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

// finally draw the grid
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
this_g.drawRect(drawSizes[0], drawSizes[1],drawSizes[0]+ drawSizes[2], drawSizes[1]+ drawSizes[3] , paint);

for(int i=1; i < 10 ; i++) {
    this_g.drawLine(drawSizes[0], drawSizes[1] + (i * drawSizes[3] / 10), drawSizes[0] + drawSizes[2], drawSizes[1] + (i * drawSizes[3] / 10), paint);
    this_g.drawLine(drawSizes[0]+ (i * drawSizes[2] / 10), drawSizes[1], drawSizes[0] + (i * drawSizes[2] / 10), drawSizes[1] + drawSizes[3], paint);
}

// good for one value
print_axis_values_4_grid(this_g, cur_elt_array[1] , Double.toString(rounded_max) , Double.toString(rounded_min), cur_elt_array[0] , 2 ,0 );
}  // --- end of draw_grid --- 

// provate void print_axis_values_4_grid(Graphics thisDrawingArea, string cur_units , string cur_max , string cur_min , string cur_label , ByVal x_guide As Integer, ByVal this_idx As Integer)
public static void print_axis_values_4_grid(Canvas canvas, String cur_units , String cur_max , String cur_min , String cur_label , int  x_guide , int  this_idx ) {
    String this_str;
    String this_str2;
    double delta = ( Double.valueOf(cur_max).doubleValue() ) / 10;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();

paint.setColor( Color.BLACK );
paint.setTypeface( Typeface.SANS_SERIF );

//Font smallyFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 12);
// thisDrawingArea.setFont(smallyFont);
paint.setTextSize(14);

for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
    // 'work our the values so is proper
    this_str =Double.toString( (Double.valueOf(cur_min).doubleValue()  + delta * i) );
    final int point = this_str.indexOf('.');
    if (point > 0) {
        // If has a decimal point, may need to clip off after or force 2 decimal places
        this_str = this_str + "00";
        this_str =  this_str.substring(0,point+3);
    } else {
        this_str = this_str + ".00";
    }
    if (i ==10) {
        this_str = "0.00";
    }
    canvas.drawText(this_str,  x_guide - 2, drawSizes[1] + drawSizes[3]  -  (i * drawSizes[3] / 10) -3, paint);
}   
for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
    // 'work our the values so is proper
    this_str2 =Double.toString( (Double.valueOf(cur_max).doubleValue()  - delta * i ) );
    final int point = this_str2.indexOf('.');
    if (point > 0) {
        // If has a decimal point, may need to clip off after or force 2 decimal places
        this_str2 = this_str2 + "00";
        this_str2 =  this_str2.substring(0,point+3);
    } else {
        this_str2 = this_str2 + ".00";
    }
    if (i == 10) {
        this_str2 = "0.00";
    }
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(-90,190,90);
    canvas.drawText(this_str2, x_guide-120, drawSizes[1] + drawSizes[3]  -  (i * drawSizes[3] / 10)-95, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
// smallyFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 12);
// thisDrawingArea.setFont(smallyFont);
paint.setTextSize(14);
}  // --- end of print_axis_values_4_grid 

private static Point  scale_point(int this_x , double this_y  , Point drawPoint, 
        int scr_x  , int scr_y  , int scr_width  , int src_height  , 
        double maxX  , double minX  , double  maxY  , double minY  ) {
    int temp_x, temp_y;
    Point temp = new Point();

if (maxY == minY)  //skip bad data
    return null;
//don't touch it if is nothing
try {
    temp_x = scr_x + (int)( ((double)this_x - minX) * ((double)scr_width / (maxX - minX)) );
    temp_y = scr_y + (int)( (maxY - this_y) * ((double)src_height / (maxY - minY)) );

    temp.x = temp_x;
    temp.y= temp_y;
    drawPoint = temp;
} catch  (Exception e) {
    return (null);
}
return temp;
} // --- end of scale_point --

public static boolean plot_array_list(Canvas this_g, Vector this_array_list , Vector these_labels , String this_title , int only_this_idx ) {
    int idx;
    int lRow ;
    int nParms;
    int  i, points_2_plot, shifted_idx ;
    int prev_x, prev_y ;
    int cur_x=0, cur_y=0 ;

//Dim ShowMarker As Object
Point cur_point = new Point();
cur_point.set(0,0);

double cur_maxX, cur_minX, cur_maxY=20, cur_minY=0, cur_rangeY;
int cur_start_x, cur_points_2_plot;
int POINTS_TO_CHANGE = 30;
double cur_OBD_val;

//Object curElt;
String curElt;
String[] cur_elt_array;
Object curElt2;
String[] cur_elt_array2;

final Paint paint = new Paint();
try { // catch in this block for some thing
    points_2_plot = this_array_list.size();
    {
        cur_start_x = 0;
        cur_points_2_plot = points_2_plot;
        cur_maxX = cur_points_2_plot;
        cur_minX = 0;
    }
    //'Create the plot points for this series from the ChartPoints array:
    curElt = (String)this_array_list.elementAt(0);
    //the lines have to come out good
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    //for(  nParms = 0 ; nParms < cur_elt_array.length ; nParms++ )
    nParms = only_this_idx;
    {
        //get cur item labels
        curElt2 = these_labels.elementAt(nParms);
        cur_elt_array2  = (String[]) curElt2;
        cur_maxY = get_ceiling_or_floor (Double.parseDouble(cur_elt_array2[2]) , true);
        cur_minY = get_ceiling_or_floor (Double.parseDouble(cur_elt_array2[3]) , false);

        cur_points_2_plot = this_array_list.size();
        cur_maxX = cur_points_2_plot;

        curElt = (String)this_array_list.elementAt(0);
        cur_OBD_val = Double.parseDouble( curElt);

        cur_point = scale_point(0, cur_OBD_val, cur_point,
                drawSizes[0], drawSizes[1], drawSizes[2], drawSizes[3],
                cur_maxX, cur_minX, cur_maxY, cur_minY); //'(CInt(curAxisValues.Mins(nParms - 2) / 5) + 1) * 5)
        cur_x = cur_point.x;
        cur_y = cur_point.y;

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        // the point is only cool when samples are low
        if ( cur_points_2_plot < POINTS_TO_CHANGE)
            this_g.drawRect(cur_x-2, cur_y-2, cur_x-2 + 4,cur_y-2+ 4 , paint);
        prev_x = cur_x;
        prev_y = cur_y;

        //'go and plot point for this parm -- pont after the 1st one
        for (lRow = cur_start_x +1 ; lRow< cur_start_x + cur_points_2_plot -1 ; lRow++) {
            curElt = (String)this_array_list.elementAt(lRow);
            cur_OBD_val = Double.parseDouble( curElt);

            //'work out an approx if cur Y values not avail(e.g. nothing)
            // if (! (cur_elt_array[nParms ] == null ) )   //skip bad one
            if( cur_OBD_val == Double.NaN) continue;  //skip bad one
            {
                cur_point=scale_point(lRow, cur_OBD_val, cur_point,
                        drawSizes[0], drawSizes[1], drawSizes[2], drawSizes[3],
                        cur_maxX, cur_minX, cur_maxY, cur_minY);
                cur_x = cur_point.x;
                cur_y = cur_point.y;
                if ( cur_points_2_plot < POINTS_TO_CHANGE)
                    this_g.drawRect(cur_x-2, cur_y-2, cur_x-2 +4, cur_y-2 + 4, paint );

                this_g.drawLine( prev_x, prev_y, cur_x, cur_y, paint);
                prev_x = cur_x;
                prev_y = cur_y;
            } // ' if end of this_array(lRow, nParms - 1)<> nothing
        } // end of for lrow
    } // end of for nParmns
    //this_g.invalidate();
    return( true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return( false);
}
} // --- end of plot_array_list  --

// need the width of the labels
private static int getCurTextLengthInPixels(Paint this_paint, String this_text) {
    FontMetrics tp = this_paint.getFontMetrics();
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    this_paint.getTextBounds(this_text, 0, this_text.length(), rect);
    return rect.width();
} // --- end of getCurTextLengthInPixels  ---

public static double get_ceiling_or_floor(double this_val ,  boolean is_max  ) {
    double this_min_tmp;
    int  this_sign;
    int  this_10_factor=0;
    double this_rounded;

if (this_val == 0.0) {
    this_rounded = 0.0;
    return this_rounded;
}

this_min_tmp = Math.abs(this_val);
if (this_min_tmp >= 1.0 && this_min_tmp < 10.0)
    this_10_factor = 1;
else if (this_min_tmp >= 10.0 && this_min_tmp < 100.0)
    this_10_factor = 10;
else if (this_min_tmp >= 100.0 && this_min_tmp < 1000.0)
    this_10_factor = 100;
else if (this_min_tmp >= 1000.0 && this_min_tmp < 10000.0)
    this_10_factor = 1000;
else if (this_min_tmp >= 10000.0 && this_min_tmp < 100000.0)
    this_10_factor = 10000;
else if (this_min_tmp >= 10000.0 && this_min_tmp < 100000.0)
    this_10_factor = 10000;
//'cover when min is pos and neg
if (is_max) {
    if (this_val > 0.0)
        this_sign = 1;
    else
        this_sign = -1;
} else {
    if (this_val > 0.0)
        this_sign = -1;
    else
        this_sign = 1;
}
if (this_min_tmp > 1)
    this_rounded = (double)(((int)(this_min_tmp / this_10_factor) + this_sign) * this_10_factor);
else {
    this_rounded = (int)(this_min_tmp * 100.0);
    //' cover same as above bfir number up to .001 less than tha it will skip
    if (this_rounded >= 1 && this_rounded < 9)
        this_10_factor = 1;
    else if (this_rounded >= 10 && this_rounded < 99)
        this_10_factor = 10;
    else if (this_rounded >= 100 && this_rounded < 999)
        this_10_factor = 100;
    this_rounded = (double)(((int)((this_rounded) / this_10_factor) + this_sign) *     this_10_factor);
    this_rounded = (int)(this_rounded) / 100.0;
}
if (this_val < 0)
    this_rounded = -this_rounded;
return  this_rounded;
} // --- end of get_ceiling_or_floor ---
```